"If I had not liked history, I would not have chosen this field of study" is this sentence true in terms of grammar?
Is it true to say:

If I had not liked history, I would not have chosen this field of study.

I mean is there any problem if we use this formula: Had not  ... + would not have ...

Not sure what you mean by "true" here. Your utterance is syntactically valid, but imho it's very unlikely compared to If I didn't like history, I wouldn't have chosen this field of study. Native Anglophones don't like Perfect verb forms anywhere near as much as EFL learners seem to. But if you want to be even more awkward, you could always go for If I hadn't have liked history, I wouldn't have... Also syntactically fine, but unlikely to come from a native speaker.

Yes, informally you'd use FumbleFingers' version, and in formal contexts inversion like "Had I not liked history" might be more usual.

I don't accept that "Had I not liked..." should be classified as "formal". It's a dated / literary construct, not formal.

If I did not like history is not unambiguously about a past liking for history that led to a career decision in the past.   There are times when you want to be clear, and if you are referring to a decision you made earlier in your life conditioned on something that was true back then, use the past perfect. It's well suited to such contexts.   If I had not liked history, I would not have applied to a history graduate program. But I did, and I did, and the rest was history.

If your question at the end is suggesting "If I had not have liked history," then no, that's not a valid construction.

"True" is not the same as "grammatical" or "idiomatic".

@TimR: The possibility that the speaker no longer likes history anyway, and that it's contextually important to convey that by using Past Perfect rather than Simple Past with do-support (conveying "irrealis") is so unlikely I don't think it justifies recommending learners should persist with their stereotypical overuse of Perfect verb forms.

@TimR It might be ambiguous in general, but in this case it's clear, since the consequence is also in the past ("would not have").

"If I didn't love you I wouldn't have married you" seems to get dozens of hits in Google Books, but there are only two instances of "If I hadn't loved you I wouldn't have married you". And let's face it, if you heard the second version you might reasonably conclude your marriage was a dead duck, anyway. This is pearls before swine, imho.

@Barmar   My point was that the past perfect has its purposes, and I'm countering FumbleFingers's frequent advice to avoid it.

@FumbleFingers I don't think that's a good example, because that "didn't" is not really simple past. Love is often considered eternal, and a statement like that might be a response to "Do you love me." Unless you qualify it (e.g. "If I didn't love you on our wedding day, ..."), it's about an ongoing state.

@Barmar: Having a liking for a subject (such as History) might be considered more "eternal, timeless", since the object of one's affections doesn't really change, whereas the person you marry will almost certainly change a lot over decades. But in any case, the point of the example was to illustrate the general meaning of that verb form, not to veracity in any given case.

The short answer to your question is Yes, you can generally use that construct, although this particular example sounds a little awkward. To me, it's less awkward if you use a contraction:

If I hadn't liked history, I wouldn't have chosen this field of study.

While it's more formal, you can also say:

Had I not liked history, I would not have chosen this field of study.

There are many other examples that sound a little less awkward:

If I hadn't given him the answers, he wouldn't have passed the test.
If I hadn't said "Yes," we wouldn't have wasted so much time.

While I agree with one of the comments that you might hear people say:

If I didn't like history, I would not have chosen this field of study.

But grammatically that's wrong because of the verb tense. "If I didn't like history" talks about your current love of history. That's not in sync with "I would not have chosen this field of study," which is a hypothetical choice in the past. If you keep the tense consistent, you can say something like:

If I didn't like history, I wouldn't be a professor in this department.

